# MySQL if string if sat beginning

Tags: mysql

I have a table where sometimes I need to replace the number at the beginning if it exists. How can I do this without matching the entire string I just want if the first 3 match?

Thanks

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(number, '338', '08')
from contacts
group by name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` or `CASE`, and use substring operations instead of `REPLACE` (because `REPLACE` will do multiple replacements, not just at the beginning).

```
SELECT NAME, IF(number LIKE '338%', CONCAT('08', SUBSTR(number, 4)), number)
FROM contacts
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! What does the number 4 represent?

Comment: That's the position in `number` to start the substring from.

Answer (score 0):

you could use LEFT() for this then CONCAT end of string.

```
select concat(replace( left(number,3),'338','08'),substr(number,4))
```

but phone numbers could be written many ways. ( +33xxxx, (33) xxxxx, 0033xxxxx, ...) This is not so simple.